# Загрузка UIView в зависимости от значения Segmented Control[закрыт]

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

Имеется view(Настройки) с segmented control(значения 1-Клиент и 2-Водитель).

Необходимо при изменении segmented control, соответсвенно, подгружать в этом же экране View1(Настройки для клиента) или View2(Настройки для водителя)

Как реализовать это правильно? 
PS. Похоже на реализацию вкладки News в приложении Instagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

посмотрите в сторону UITabBar, UIToolBar они для этого и сделаны.